# Why does Magento Setup:Upgrade fail when ConfigurableSampleData module is updating?

Tags: cli, magento2.3.4, setup-upgrade, sample-data

I have attempted installing Magento in several ways.  With and without sample data.  This last time I have installed primarily using the CLI method however when I attempt to install sample data and I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I have the following error.  What could be wrong?  I also have the WebInstaller stall at 66% when it arrives at the `ConfigurableSampleData` section.

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true."},"status":400}
```

Error message in terminal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIpk5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Same is found in my CLI.i have remove the sample data and again run sample data

remove the sample data :-

```
php bin/magento sampledata:remove
```

And after run the :

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Check this link :-

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-sample-data/

Thanks...